# How does the Mobile feat interact with the Writhing Tide for a Swarmkeeper Ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger

In the Swarmkeeper section for Rangers in  *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* there is an ability called **Writing Tide** (TCoE, p.60), which allows the Ranger to fly.

> **Writhing Tide**
>
> *7th-level Swarmkeeper feature*
>
> You can condense part of your swarm into a focused mass that lifts you up. As a bonus action, you gain a flying speed of 10 feet and can hover. The effect lasts for 1 minute.
>
> You can use this feature a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regainall expended uses when you finish a long rest.

In the *Player's Handbook* the feat Mobile (PHB, p.168).

> You are exceptionally speedy and agile. You gain the
> following benefits:
>
> • Your speed increases by 10 feet.
>
> • When you use the Dash action, difficult terrain doesn’t cost you extra movement on that turn.
>
> • When you make a melee attack against a creature, you don’t provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest o f the turn, whether you hit or not.

**Does this mean that if you take Mobile as a feat, the benefit would apply to this particular feature too - effectively having a fly movement of 20 feet instead?**

Comment: I think the link answers it in theory, but it would be good if someone bothered to explain their thinking in an answer to my specific question about this Ranger feature and the Mobile feat? The link that was put is for a monk feature and the Fly spell - so, though the link may suggest the answer I don't think this qustion is a "duplicate" of that one.

Comment: The answer marked as a duplicate establishes that anything benefitting your speed benefits all your speeds. I believe that sufficiently answers your question as the Mobile feat benefits your speed (exactly like Unarmored Movement) and the Writhing Tide feature grants a speed (exactly like the *fly* spell). If there is something particularly different about these features, it would be good to edit that into your question

Comment: Thanks Medix2. I still think it needs to be answered, if only to explain the links. It is not "exactly" the same; thought the comment you put contains a good answer. I think it would be a dupliate if it was the Mobile and Fly feat, but it is not. Besides, Unarmored Movement changes with advancement in the Monk class, the Mobile does not. There are two points of variance - though the answer seems to be  "yes, it does". Just closing a question as duplicate does not allow for varying points of view either.

Comment: @Senmurv Please edit your reasons for thinking this question is different into the question, or why you think the equivalence isn't obvious, ie. what your two points of variance are and why you think it matters. As for what you're running into, you are in disagreement with several community members regarding the dupe status. Address the concerns raised in comments and if you want broader or more detailed input feel free to open a meta question, but please don't resort to name calling (edited that out of your comment for you)