# How does the movement enhancement from Mobile feat interact with the movement speeds of class and sub-class features?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, movement

The **Mobile** feat appears in the *Player's Handbook* (PHB, p.168) and would be generally accessible to all classes and races as long as DM agrees to allow feats at the table.

> You are exceptionally speedy and agile. You gain the
> following benefits:
>
> • Your speed increases by 10 feet.

There are certain class or sub-class features that allow a PC to have increase in movement (walking) such as: a Barbarian's *Fast Movement* (+10 feet), a Monk's *Unarmored Movement* (+10 to +30 feet), or a Druid's *Wildshape* (walking, depending on the beast), a Scout Rogue's *Skirmisher* (reaction, moves half their speed).

There are also certain class or sub-class features that modify existing or provide additional movement options other than walking, such as: Swarmkeeper Ranger's *Writhing Tide* (10 feet flying), Twilight Cleric's *Steps of the Night* (10 feet flying), or a Ranger's *Deft Explorer* (+5 feet; climbing/swimming speed sam as walking), a Druid's *Wildshape* (swimming/flying, depending on the beast), Phantom Rogue's *Ghost Walk* (10 feet flying), The Fathomless Warlock's *Gift of the Sea* (40 feet swimming).

I'm looking for an answer for this specific question with relation to how the Mobile feat interacts with class/sub-class features which provide adjustments to movement speeds.

From what I gather all these class/sub-class features would add a +10 feet movement, e.g. a Warlock with the The Fathomless sub-class who takes the Mobile feat would have a 50 feet swimming speed.

Is this correct?

Thanks for the clarification/confirmation on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this for now, as this is nearly the [same question you asked yesterday](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178903/how-does-the-mobile-feat-interact-with-the-writhing-tide-for-a-swarmkeeper-range) that the community left closed as a duplicate of the linked question. I leave it to the community to reopen.

Comment: If you disagree with the duplicate nature of your question(s) you should open a discussion on meta rather than just reposting closed questions.

Comment: @Senmurv The other question's answer states that a generic speed increase (like the mobile feat) applies to all speeds, including fly speeds from sources like class features.

Comment: The community has decided that the question has a suitable answer elsewhere. Reposting the question is not the way to go if you disagree. That's why Thomas Markov closed the question. I told you what the way to go is and people seem to agree. If you want to have the question reopened you should make your case on meta. That's not a guarantee but it will get you further than reposting or the comments under the reposts.